Client side fetching and NextJS. Should react-query be used?
The nextjs app docs don't really give much information when it comes to client side data fetching.
One section mentions that requests are deduplicated  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns
"If you need to use the same data (e.g. current user) in multiple components in a tree, you do not have to fetch data globally, nor forward props between components. Instead, you can use fetch or React
cache in the component that needs the data without worrying about the performance implications of making multiple requests for the same data."
Does the entire caching magic only concern fetch calls made on the server side or do we also gain something in the client components?
My experience mostly is with non next frameworks where I got used to react query for this task. There is a tiny section talking about using 3rd party libraries to fetch data client side e.g. SWR or react query. (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-client-with-third-party-libraries).
Using react query alongside nextjs enhanced fetch if both provide a caching layer sounds like a terible idea if it isn't handled carefully or am I missunderstanding something greatly?
Edit:
Here is a simple situation of an example. A user selects an item from a list and based on the selection data needs to be loaded on the fly. As far as I understand server actions do not apply here because we are not working with forms.
export default function ClientComponent() {
  const [id, setId] = useEffect<number | null>(null);

  // fetch based on selected id

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setId(1)}>Select Item</Button>
      <OtherComponent articleId={id} />
    </>
  );
}


